# Push an object on rabbitMQ queue

Tags: php, rabbitmq, message-queue, publish-subscribe, amqp

**Problem statement:**

I have certain objects which are required to build a message. In my application building message is a heavy operation hence instead of pushing message to queue, I want my publisher push those objects on queue. Once subscriber listens the queue, it will pick those objects and build message.

Is there any solution in rabbitMQ to solve this problem? I am using php-amqplib

Comment: Show us your attempt.. we aren't your code monkeys :)

Answer (score 2):

this sounds a bit like a chicken-and-egg problem... you need to build a message, but it takes a long time. so you want to send a message to have the message built? :)

the best way to do this, in my experience, is to send a very small message through rabbitmq - one that only contains a database id or some other small amount of information that can be used to look up the complete data set that you need. on the other ends of the queue, use that id / small data set to load the complete data / object model that you need, and then go about building your final message to push through rabbitmq again.

the thing is, you can't push an object through RabbitMQ. at least, not the way developers think about objects as in-memory chucks of code and data. you can really only push data through rabittmq. so, you have to convert your object in to a data structure that can be sent. this means you either build a JSON document of the full object, or you just send the object's ID from the database.

if you send a full document describing all of the data in the object, then you can reconstruct a facsimile of the original object with just that data. but this tends to make heavy messages that slow down rabbitmq.

if you send just a database id, you can re-load the full object from the database on the other end of the queue. this assumes you have the database available, and that the data will not have changed in the time between sending the id and reloading the object.

so, there's tradeoffs... but it sounds like you might want to try sending an id as the message, and loading the full object on the back-end.